# jboss seam deployment error

Tags: jboss, seam, jboss-tools

I am using the JBoss Tools to deploy a seam application to a JBoss server from within eclipse. I am consistently seeing a strange behavior. Every time the .xhtml files are changed the seam application is auto-deployed as expected. However, the entity manager instance is becoming null and I am forced forced to restart the seam application by removing it and adding it through the eclipse server view. The whole process is taking more time than I can afford. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Try to use the seam-gen app that is bundled with seam, then use only the build provided by the seam-gen to build, explode and other stuff like that.

Comment: That's wierd. Resources like xhtml work even without JBoss hot deplyment feature. Maybe is something wrong with your eclipse/jboss tools configuration. Try create simple Seam project and see whether it will work.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/gettingstartedwithjbosstools.html

Comment: Adding a little more about what cetnar told, if you're using hb-tools, make sure you mark use local jboss folder on jboss otherwise eclipse 3.4 messes up with hot deploy.

Answer (score 1):

If you change a xhtml file only that single file should be copied and the entitymanager should not be affected. Are you refreshing the browser ? Triggering some specific action on that page ?

Comment: whoops - that should have been a comment not a answer.

Comment: I am changing the .xhtml. Waiting for Jboss to publish it. and refreshing the browser. Yet I keep getting the EntityManager is null exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you use JBoss 5.1.0 server? If yes, there are a bunch of problems with this server while working with Seam especially [in version 2.2.0](http://www.jboss.org/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=159500). You may also read about [general](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatHappensWhenYouDeploySeamAppInJBoss5) problems with deployment to JBoss5 container.

The other thing you must remeber is to set debug mode for Seam and development mode for facelets. Whitout this two configurations hot deployment won't work.